# Custom Message Key in Hibernate validator not working with message.property

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, hibernate-validator, jsr330

I am working on Spring Boot, I have used Hibernate Validator to validate my beans. I have added a custom key with the `@NotEmpty` annotation, and add thos key/value pair in message.properties, but it's not getting its value from message.property

Here is my bean with validation annotation:

```
public class CategoryBean {
    @NotEmpty(message = "{category.name.notempty}")
    private String name;
    ----getter setter-----
}
```

message.properties (path:src/main/resources/message.properties)

```
category.name.notempty=Sorry! Category can't be empty
```

I have also configured message resource

```
@Bean
public MessageSource messageSource() {
    ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
    messageSource.setBasename("message");
    return messageSource;
}
```

I also configured `LocalValidatorFactoryBean`

```
@Bean
public LocalValidatorFactoryBean validator() {
    final LocalValidatorFactoryBean localValidatorFactoryBean = new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
    localValidatorFactoryBean.setValidationMessageSource(messageSource());
    return localValidatorFactoryBean;
}
```

Whenever I am validating this bean, it's showing its key instead of its value.
Hibernate validator default search message key inside `ValidationMessages.properties` so whenever I am adding `ValidationMessages.properties` file add there message this key value then it's working fine for me.

But I don't want to add ValidationMessage.properties file, instead of this I want to handle this message key in my message.properties file.

I know there are already some question related this in stack overflow, but those solutions are not solving my problem. I am unable to find out what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: Is the folder really called `reasources`? Because it should be `resources`. Also property files usually have extension `.properties` not `.property`.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel  i am sorry, it was typo during the writing the description. I have update the description.

Answer (score 2):

I can mistake with explonation, but I think that
The **main problem** why you cannot resolve validation message key for `NotEmpty` with Spring MessageSource is Spring Boot auto configuration `ValidationAutoConfiguration`.

When you are using Spring Boot, it adds org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.validation.ValidationAutoConfiguration where the **defaultValidator** component which looks something like this:

```
@Bean
@Role(BeanDefinition.ROLE_INFRASTRUCTURE)
@ConditionalOnMissingBean(Validator.class)
public static LocalValidatorFactoryBean defaultValidator() {
    LocalValidatorFactoryBean factoryBean = new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
    MessageInterpolatorFactory interpolatorFactory = new MessageInterpolatorFactory();
    factoryBean.setMessageInterpolator(interpolatorFactory.getObject());
    return factoryBean;
}
```

As you can see this factoryBean sets MessageInterpolator from MessageInterpolatorFactory using getObject() method which contains code:

```
return Validation.byDefaultProvider().configure()
                .getDefaultMessageInterpolator();
```

that returns default Hibernate `org.hibernate.validator.messageinterpolation.ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator`

Therefore `Validator` will use default Hibernate `ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator` to resolve validation message in ValidationMessages.properties file.

If you want to override default Hibernate `ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator` with own, you need put `@Primary` to your `LocalValidatorFactoryBean`:

```
@Bean
public MessageSource messageSource() {
    final ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
    messageSource.setBasenames("classpath:messages");
    return messageSource;
}

@Bean
@Primary
public LocalValidatorFactoryBean validatorBean(MessageSource messageSource) {
    final LocalValidatorFactoryBean bean = new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
    bean.setValidationMessageSource(messageSource);
    return bean;
}
```

And then Validator will use your `LocalValidatorFactoryBean` with `MessageSourceResourceBundleLocator` to resolve validation messages in messages.propeties file.

Comment: If that's the case, is there a way to modify Spring Boot's provided `Validator` with `ValidationAutoConfiguration`? Why should we create a new one in the first place? My concern is regarding the rest of features provided for us via auto configuration, e.g. an advice and point cut by `MethodValidationPostProcessor` to trigger validation access strategy? Would the custom `@Primary Validator` created above be able to take advantage of those Spring Boot provided features?

Comment: I think that all will work, because we create custom validator and Spring usually before wrap validator checks that we have one in application context and using this.
For example you can see `WebMvcAutoConfiguration.EnableWebMvcConfiguration#mvcValidator` where spring before create new valiudator checks that we have one.
What about `MethodValidationPostProcessor` it only uses bean that represent `Validator` class and it can be custom or default validator I think it doesn't matter for Spring.

Comment: @Malvon I had exactly the same concern as you and came up with [this solution](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/26149#issuecomment-734290699).

Answer (score 0):

Give a try with this, replacing your MessageSource with this:

```
@Bean
public MessageSource messageSource() {
    ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
    messageSource.setBasenames("classpath:/messages");
    messageSource.setUseCodeAsDefaultMessage(false);
    messageSource.setCacheSeconds((int) TimeUnit.HOURS.toSeconds(1));
    messageSource.setFallbackToSystemLocale(false);
    return messageSource;
}
```

You have to put your message `category.name.notempty=Sorry! Category can't be empty` inside `resources/messages.properties` file

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem. but I've solved now.
My methods are simple.

1. DO NOT USE `@EnableWebMvc`
2. DO NOT EXTENDS `org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport`

Good luck.